# I want to calculate user radius and retrieve the user id in android Firebase

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want that when user uploads posts so the notification should be sent to the user in 10 km radius. For this, I am calculating user radius by retrieving user latitude and longitude from firebase database and sending them to the `distanceBetween` function one by one along with the latitude and longitude of the post from where it is uploaded. But the problem is that which user comes in the radius.And I am unable to retrieve the user id and reg Token to send a notification.

Here is my code

```
dataref.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
                            {
                             datasnap = data;
                                            }

Location.distanceBetween(Post_latitude, Post_longitude,Double.parseDouble(datasnap.child("latitude").getValue(String.class)), Double.parseDouble(datasnap.child("longitude").getValue(String.class)), results);
                        final double km = (results[0] / 1000);

                        if (km <= 10000) {
                            if (!String.valueOf(datasnap.getKey().toString()).equals(userID)) {

                //getting the user id here

                               Log.d("USerID", datasnap.getKey().toString() )
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

[Here is my database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AwEK.png)

Comment: Why not calculate the necessary latitude and longitude range for the users in the database. Create a query that returns only those users (and their tokens) within that radius and then send a notification to all those users. Check the Firebase documentation to see how to send a notification to multiple users.

Comment: sending notification is not a problem but the thing is i am unable to create something what you are saying. creating a query that calculate and return only the necessary TOKENS.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you unsure how to calculating the distance? Or are you unsure how to write the query?

Comment: i am calculating the distance in "Location,distanceBetween()" function. and doing the query in this way. but its not appropriate though.
final double km = (results[0] / 1000); 
if (km <= 10000)

Comment: but i guess my query is not that what i need..right.. if you can guide me right.

Comment: I have done something similar to what you need. But I have used a MySQL database which uses standard SQL queries. I am familiar with Firebase Messaging but not familiar with Firebase Database or the table structures or available data types.

Comment: If defining the query is your main issue I suggest that you research how to query the Firebase Database. If that is not fruitful than pose a new question asking for help on formulating a Firebase Database query. I wish you good luck!

Comment: Still trying. But Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of my problem.
Use geofire to save and retrieve user location with in a specified radius.

here is the code:

// creates a new query around [37.7832, -122.4056] with a radius of 0.6 kilometers
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(37.7832, -122.4056), 0.6);

For details check the link: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java